# Azure Automation Powershell to Refresh Lower Level Databases

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I am using the script from the website below to automate the refresh of lower environment databases from our production database.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/how-to-automate-azure-sql-managed-instance-database-copy-and/ba-p/3874505

If I run this script from my local machine, it does exactly what it's supposed to do. However, when I publish it and run it from Azure as a runbook, it does not. But, I can't figure out how to get some sort of error message to tell me what's wrong.

I am using a managed identity which is defined in the script. I have turned on verbose logging and still am not able to figure out what is missing. Since the script runs perfectly locally, it seems to me the issue would have to be permissions, right? But I can't figure out what permissions or missing (or whether there is some other issue).

This is my first attempt at Azure Automation and I see a great deal of benefit from using it but I have to get passed this first hurdle. Below is my existing code:

```
# Newest version for testing
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process

# Connect to Azure with user-assigned managed identity
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId "user-defined-managed-id here").context

# set and store context
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext

# Select UAT Subscription
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId [non-prod subscription id here]

$dbNames = @("Mv_SISD", "Mv_SISD_GEO", "Mv_SISD_WO")
$sourceMi = "sqlmi-prd-02"
$sourceRg = "SQL-Prod"
$targetMi = "sqlmi-dev-02"
$targetRg = "SQL-UAT"

$timeout = $false

$expectedDuration = New-TimeSpan -Days 0 -Hours 1 -Minutes 30
$startTime = Get-Date

Write-Host "Starting drop operation for databases: "
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++) { Write-Host $dbNames[$i] " "}

## Start drop for all databases in the list.
##
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++)
{
    $vmExists = Get-AzResource -Name $dbNames[$i] -ResourceGroupName $targetRg
    if ($vmExists) {
    Remove-AzSqlInstanceDatabase -Name $dbNames[$i] -InstanceName $targetMi -ResourceGroupName $targetRg -Force}
    else {
        Write-Output "VM $dbnames[$i] does not exist, skipping."
    }
}

##$allDropsSucceeded = $true

# Select PROD Subscription
Write-Host "Switch to Prod subscription: "
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId [prod subscription id here] 

Write-Host "Starting copy operation for databases: "
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++) { Write-Host $dbNames[$i] " "}

## Start copy for all databases in the list.
##
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++)
{
    Copy-AzSqlInstanceDatabase -DatabaseName $dbNames[$i] -InstanceName $sourceMi -ResourceGroupName $sourceRg -TargetInstanceName $targetMi -TargetResourceGroupName $targetRg -AsJob | Format-Table -Property Name, PSBeginTime, State
}

$allCopiesSucceeded = $true

while($true)
{
    if ((Get-Date) -gt $startTime + $expectedDuration)
    {
        Write-Host "Script timeout. Terminating the script."
        $timeout = $true
        break
    }

    Write-Host "Getting the status of operations..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    $operations = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

    ## Get status of all copy operations.
    ##
    for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++)
    {
        $operations += Get-AzSqlInstanceDatabaseCopyOperation -DatabaseName $dbNames[$i] -InstanceName $sourceMi -ResourceGroupName $sourceRg -TargetInstanceName $targetMi -TargetResourceGroupName $targetRg -OnlyLatestPerDatabase
    }

    try
    {
        $allCopiesSucceeded = $true;
        for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++)
        {
            ## Call with -AsJob, because this is long running operation (size of data),
            ## and we want to parallelize calls for multiple databases.
            ##
            Write-Host "Status of copy for " $dbNames[$i] " is " $operations[$i].State
            if (!($operations[$i].State -eq "Succeeded")) { $allCopiesSucceeded = $false; }
        }
    }
    catch { $allCopiesSucceeded = $false; Write-Host "Oops, something went wrong. Retrying..." }

    if ($allCopiesSucceeded)
    {
        Write-Host "All operations ready for completion!"
        break
    }
    else { Write-Host "Copying in progress..." }

    Write-Host "Waiting a bit..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}

if ($allCopiesSucceeded -and !$timeout) 
{
    ## Let's complete all database copy operations.
    ##
    Write-Host "Completing all database copy operations..."

    for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++)
    {
        ## Call with -AsJob, because this is not super quick operation
        ## and we want to parallelize calls for multiple databases.
        ##
        Complete-AzSqlInstanceDatabaseCopy -DatabaseName $dbNames[$i] -InstanceName $sourceMi -ResourceGroupName $sourceRg -TargetInstanceName $targetMi -TargetResourceGroupName $targetRg -AsJob | Format-Table -Property Name, PSBeginTime, State
    }

    $completeDone = $true

    while($true)
    {
        Write-Host "Getting the status of copy complete operations..."
        $completeOperations = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

        for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++)
        {
            $completeOperations += Get-AzSqlInstanceDatabaseCopyOperation -DatabaseName $dbNames[$i] -InstanceName $sourceMi -ResourceGroupName $sourceRg -TargetInstanceName $targetMi -TargetResourceGroupName $targetRg -OnlyLatestPerDatabase
        }

        try
        {
            $completeDone = $true
            for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++)
            {
                Write-Host "Status of copy completion for " $dbNames[$i] " is " $completeOperations[$i].State
                if (!($completeOperations[$i].State -eq "Succeeded")) { $completeDone = $false; }
            }
        }
        catch { Write-Host "Oops, something went wrong. Retrying..." }

        if ($completeDone)
        {
            Write-Host "Database copy succeeded for databases: "
            for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++) { Write-Host $dbNames[$i] " "}

            break
        }
        else { Write-Host "Complete in progress..." }

        Write-Host "Waiting a bit..."
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag since this isn't related to the SQL _language_. Instead you should add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: I would start by using SQL Server Management Studio and connect to server. The log files can be found in the explorer under Management. The log files will show the group and user for every connection to the database. You can compare the group/user from working and non working query. If you do no see the connection than the error either before the connection is made or the connection is failing.  I would also check the event viewer on the server to see if there are any errors.  Or even task manager to see if code is running.  Is app running as a service?  What account are you using for service.

Comment: Currently, it's theoretically running as the managed identity whether I run from my machine or from Azure. But, that wouldn't make sense either. Let me do some digging into the logs and see if I can find anything helpful.

Comment: You should be able to see Azure Automation output somewhere. Can you see the Write-Host messages? Have you added the managed identity to the source and target SQL Servers?

Comment: The following may help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/troubleshooting?view=azps-11.4.0

Comment: Have you tried with system managed identity instead of user identity? @camromere

Answer (score 0):

When running a PowerShell script locally, you may not require explicit permissions for specific resources. However, when executing the same script within an Azure Automation runbook, it's essential to grant the necessary permissions to the relevant user or admin or managed identity.

To access and interact with SQL Managed Instances, you must assign the `"SQL Managed Instance Contributor"` role to the user. This can be done by visiting `"Access Control"` and adding a `role assignment` under both SQL Managed instances as shown below.

Additionally, ensure that the `system managed identity or user managed identity` has the `"Automation Contributor"` role enabled within the Azure Automation account.

[image]

I have tried to execute your script in my automation account set up with system managed identity and was able to perform it as expected.

```bash
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$dbNames = @("mydb","mydbj")
$sourceMi = "instance12"
$sourceRg = "xxx"
$targetMi = "instance22"
$targetRg = "xxx"
$timeout = $false

$expectedDuration = New-TimeSpan -Days 0 -Hours 1 -Minutes 30
$startTime = Get-Date
Write-Host "Starting drop operation for databases: "
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++) { Write-Host $dbNames[$i] " "}
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++)
{
    $vmExists = Get-AzResource -Name $dbNames[$i] -ResourceGroupName $targetRg
    if ($vmExists) {
    Remove-AzSqlInstanceDatabase -Name $dbNames[$i] -InstanceName $targetMi -ResourceGroupName $targetRg -Force}
    else {
        Write-Output "VM $dbnames[$i] does not exist, skipping."
    }
}

Write-Host "Starting copy operation for databases: "
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++) { Write-Host $dbNames[$i] " "}

## Start copy for all databases in the list.
##
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++)
{
    Copy-AzSqlInstanceDatabase -DatabaseName $dbNames[$i] -InstanceName $sourceMi -ResourceGroupName $sourceRg -TargetInstanceName $targetMi -TargetResourceGroupName $targetRg -AsJob | Format-Table -Property Name, PSBeginTime, State
}

$allCopiesSucceeded = $true

while($true)
{
    if ((Get-Date) -gt $startTime + $expectedDuration)
    {
        Write-Host "Script timeout. Terminating the script."
        $timeout = $true
        break
    }

    Write-Host "Getting the status of operations..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    $operations = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++)
    {
        $operations += Get-AzSqlInstanceDatabaseCopyOperation -DatabaseName $dbNames[$i] -InstanceName $sourceMi -ResourceGroupName $sourceRg -TargetInstanceName $targetMi -TargetResourceGroupName $targetRg -OnlyLatestPerDatabase
    }

    try
    {
        $allCopiesSucceeded = $true;
        for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++)
        {
            ## Call with -AsJob, because this is long running operation (size of data),
            ## and we want to parallelize calls for multiple databases.
            ##
            Write-Host "Status of copy for " $dbNames[$i] " is " $operations[$i].State
            if (!($operations[$i].State -eq "Succeeded")) { $allCopiesSucceeded = $false; }
        }
    }
    catch { $allCopiesSucceeded = $false; Write-Host "Oops, something went wrong. Retrying..." }

    if ($allCopiesSucceeded)
    {
        Write-Host "All operations ready for completion!"
        break
    }
    else { Write-Host "Copying in progress..." }

    Write-Host "Waiting a bit..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}

if ($allCopiesSucceeded -and !$timeout) 
{
    ## Let's complete all database copy operations.
    ##
    Write-Host "Completing all database copy operations..."

    for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++)
    {
        ## Call with -AsJob, because this is not super quick operation
        ## and we want to parallelize calls for multiple databases.
        ##
        Complete-AzSqlInstanceDatabaseCopy -DatabaseName $dbNames[$i] -InstanceName $sourceMi -ResourceGroupName $sourceRg -TargetInstanceName $targetMi -TargetResourceGroupName $targetRg -AsJob | Format-Table -Property Name, PSBeginTime, State
    }

    $completeDone = $true

    while($true)
    {
        Write-Host "Getting the status of copy complete operations..."
        $completeOperations = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

        for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++)
        {
            $completeOperations += Get-AzSqlInstanceDatabaseCopyOperation -DatabaseName $dbNames[$i] -InstanceName $sourceMi -ResourceGroupName $sourceRg -TargetInstanceName $targetMi -TargetResourceGroupName $targetRg -OnlyLatestPerDatabase
        }

        try
        {
            $completeDone = $true
            for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++)
            {
                Write-Host "Status of copy completion for " $dbNames[$i] " is " $completeOperations[$i].State
                if (!($completeOperations[$i].State -eq "Succeeded")) { $completeDone = $false; }
            }
        }
        catch { Write-Host "Oops, something went wrong. Retrying..." }

        if ($completeDone)
        {
            Write-Host "Database copy succeeded for databases: "
            for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $dbNames.count; $i++) { Write-Host $dbNames[$i] " "}

            break
        }
        else { Write-Host "Complete in progress..." }

        Write-Host "Waiting a bit..."
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    }
}
```

*Note*: If you have full control over the resources within your resource group, granting the `"Owner"` role provides thorough access, including the ability to read, modify, and interact with all resources.

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm working through your script using the system managed identity. Does the script you have account for restoring from a separate subscription?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on your issue? @camromere

Comment: The purpose of the runbook is to drop databases on our dev managed instance and then restore them from production managed instance on two separate Azure subscriptions. I have it open in Visual Studio Code on my laptop. When I right click on it and Run Local, the script runs perfectly and does exactly what it's supposed to do. However, when I publish that runbook to Azure, it does not do the same thing. It will drop the databases, but it does not restore them from Production. I can't see any error messages. I've run Profiler and looked at the SQL logs and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Have you checked the runtime version of local and on premises which is Azure. Make sure they both are same. @camromere

Comment: Yes my local machine and the CLI window from inside Azure are both running:

PSVersion                      7.4.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.4.1
OS                             CBL-Mariner/Linux
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0

Comment: For me it worked as detailed above. I am surprised why it is not working for you though we both have same environment configuration. @camromere

Comment: How can I verify the permissions in place versus what permissions are required for the source managed instance as well as the destination managed instance?

Comment: Verify permissions for? @camromere

Comment: I need to be able to understand why the runbook is not doing what it should. Since it runs perfectly from my laptop logged in as me, it seems like it would have to be a permissions issue either on the production managed instance or the uat managed instance.

Comment: Have you tried adding the role which I shared in the answer? @camromere